# RSpec request specs and routing specs occasionally failing in CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, jenkins, rspec-rails

We're using Jenkins as a CI server, and without any pattern that I can determine, sometimes the request and routing specs fail - only on the CI server though, never on the development machines.

It's currently using Selenium as the Capybara driver, and I've seen problems with that configuration before, but the routing specs failing sporadically is baffling me.  Can anybody make any suggestions for things to check?

Update:

I have a single failure now happening sporadically:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_a' for false:FalseClass
(in /blah/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)

/home/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/selector/simple_sequence.rb:153:in `block in to_a'
```

This is definitely the same error message I've seen before, but I've never seen the line before... investigating.

Comment: Can you provide the failures?

Comment: Sorry - it's gone out of the Jenkins history now and seems to have stopped happening (a little scary).  I will post the error if it ever occurs again, but if I recall correctly if it was something generic like "no method [] for True:TrueClass".

Comment: It stopped happening around the time that I put in code to print the full stacktrace, naturally.  I wonder if that fixed it somehow.